# collectionview indexPathForSelectedRow

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

So I changed from using `UITableView` to `UICollectionView` in my `UIViewController`, and I am stuck with a segue issue.

Earlier I used to do this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        
        if segue.identifier == "toDetail" {
            
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let vc = segue.destination as! VehicleViewController
                vc.vehicle = data![indexPath.row]
            }
            
        }
    }
```

How should this look like on the `UICollectionView` as `collectionView.indexPathForSelectedRow` is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following -

```
if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
    // Do what you want
}
```